# How to split a procedure in few logic parts?

Tags: vb.net

Hi, I'm creating a downloader by halving it in steps so that each part works logically.

The code is divided into:

```
    public class Form1

 Public Shared link As String 'I'm sharing data with another form
```

I insert a url to download in the textchanged event of textbox:

```
If (My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio = "") Then
            Label2.Text = "Download folder is missing"
            ' MsgBox("manca destinazione")
        Else
            If Clipboard.GetText.Contains("youtube") = False Then
                Label2.Text = "not a valid youtube link"
            Else
                If TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText Then
                    Label2.Text = "you already use it"
                Else

                    TextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText
                    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.320youtube.com/v8/watch?v=" +
                                _TextBox1.Text.Replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", ""))
                End If
            End If
        End If
```

Then, in the document completed event I extract the download link:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim collection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        Dim a As String
        For Each element As HtmlElement In collection
            If element.TagName = "A" Then
                a = element.GetAttribute("HREF")
                If a.Length > 70 Then
                    a.ToString.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
                    link = a
                  
                    If link IsNot Nothing Then
                        Title()

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

If the link variable is not empty then I activate the sub title:

```
Private Sub Title()
        
        Dim wctitolo As New WebClient()
        wctitolo.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8

        Dim source As String = wctitolo.DownloadString(TextBox1.Text.Replace(" - YouTube", ""))
        Dim title As String = Regex.Match(source, "\<title\b[^>]*\>\s*(?<Title>[\s\S]*?)\</title\>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups("Title").Value
        Dim a As String = title.Replace(" - YouTube", "")
        Dim webdecode As String = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(a)

        My.Settings.Titolo = String.Join("-", webdecode.Split(IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars))
        Label2.Text = "Getting title..- Step 3/4"
        Label1.Text = My.Settings.Titolo
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbLf + My.Settings.Titolo + Environment.NewLine)
        formcs.BetterListBox1.Items.Add(My.Settings.Titolo)
        My.Settings.Save()
        
        If Fileexist() Then

        Else
              If My.Settings.Titolo IsNot Nothing Then
                Download()
            End If
        End If
```

and sub FileExists () which returns true if the file exists and false if it does not exist. If it does not exist then, as dictated in private sub Title (), I activate the private sub Download ().

```
Public Function Fileexist() As Boolean
        Label3.Text = Label3.Text + "Fileesiste+ "
        Dim result As Boolean
        Dim cartella = My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio
        Dim filedidestinazione = Directory.GetFiles(cartella,
                                            My.Settings.Titolo + ".mp3",
                                              SearchOption.AllDirectories).FirstOrDefault()
        If filedidestinazione IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim answer As String
            answer = CType(MsgBox("File exist in" + vbLf + My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio + "\" + My.Settings.Titolo + ".mp3" + vbLf + "Would you like to open the folder?", vbYesNo), String)
            If CType(answer, Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBoxResult) = vbYes Then
                Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," & filedidestinazione)
                result = True
            Else
                result = False
               answer = CType(vbNo, String)
               
                Label2.Text = "File exist"

            End If
        End If
        Return result
    End Function
```

and at the end, the Download sub:

```
   Public WithEvents mclient As New WebClient
   Private Sub mClient_DownloadProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadProgressChanged

       Try
           Label4.Text = (Val(e.BytesReceived) / 1048576).ToString("0.00") & "MB Scaricati"


           Label2.Text = "Download di " + My.Settings.Titolo + " in corso.."
       Catch ex As Exception
       End Try
   End Sub
Private Sub Download()
       Label3.Text = Label3.Text + "Download+ "
       Dim filepath As String = (My.Settings.Cartellasalvataggio + "\" + Label1.Text + ".mp3")
       mclient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
       ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       mclient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "")

       mclient.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(link), filepath)
   End Sub
```

I thought everything was fine, but at runtime I get an error for stackoverflow ..

The "Settings.Designer.vb" tab opens with the error

```
System.StackOverflowException in
   <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
         Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")>  _
        Public Property Titolo() As String
            Get
                Return CType(Me("Titolo"),String)
            End Get
            Set
                Me("Titolo") = value
            End Set
        End Property
```

is there an easy way I can concatenate these pieces of code in such a way that they work in a logical step by step without modifying to much the code?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the call stacks? Seems you accidentally start a recursion somewhere

Comment: Endeed you are right, there was a stackoverflow on another line of the code. Now it seems working fine but they are workiing on top of each others. I mean, To double check when those private sub are "working", I'm using a label in the beginning on every private sub with for example : label1.text="Taking title" or "Download etc. 
The fact is that the label is being update all in once. Suddenly I see the label containing all of those (taking title, downloading etc) which is making me believe they are working all in once at the same time, eventhough the download is working though.

Comment: @Martheen , is this the correct way in order to split a procedure like mine? Would you suggest something? Thanks!!!

Comment: Update your question with the callstack when the error happen so we can figure out just where are the recursion happen

Comment: @martheen The problem referred to an other piece of the code i thought wasn't the actual problem. With callstack I sow the line of the code and I simply deleted as it was a copy paste mistake.

Comment: So the code now works? If so, this belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @martheen, yes as I said in the previous comment the code now it works. Just a thing. Now it seems working fine but they are workiing on top of each others. I mean, To double check when those private sub are "working", I'm using a label in the beginning on every private sub with for example : label1.text="Taking title" or "Download etc. The fact is that the label is being update all in once. Suddenly I see the label containing all of those (taking title, downloading etc) which is making me believe they are working all in once at the same time, eventhough the download is working though.

Comment: What I was expecting was label updating step by step from the private subs, instead It is being updates all in once. Do you know how can I let run a private sub one by one? There is something wrong on my code that you want to suggest me to add/remove? Thanks

Comment: check this gif to understand [link](https://imgur.com/a/Q5S8rDG)